# Make a USSD call in Xamarin Crossplatform app

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android, cross-platform, ussd

I want to make a USSD call in a xamarin crossplatform app using C# and i have no idea where to start. All the examples i have seen is done in java. Is it possible to successfully dial a USSD code like *270# within my app without opening the dialer? If yes, please how? I'll be very grateful for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do it with Xamarin forms you have to create a custom renderer for android :

Create an interface in your shared project :

```
public interface IUssdRenderer
{
    void StartTransaction();
}
```

then in your android project :

using System;
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;
using ussd.Renderers;

[assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Dependency(typeof(IUssdRenderer))]
namespace ussd.Droid.Renderers
{
    public class UssdRenderer : IUssdRenderer
    {
        public Android.Net.Uri createUriFromString(string ussd)
        {

```
        String uri = "tel:";
        foreach (char c in ussd.ToCharArray())
        {
            if (c == '#')
            {
                uri += Android.Net.Uri.Encode("#");
            }
            else
            {
                uri += c;
            }
        }
        return Android.Net.Uri.Parse(uri);
    }

    public void StartTransaction()
    {
        var intent = new Intent(Intent.ActionCall, createUriFromString("*270#"));
        Context ctx = Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Context;
        ctx.StartActivity(intent);
    }
}
}
```

You'll also have to register you interface, I'm using prism :

```
    public void RegisterTypes(IContainerRegistry containerRegistry)
    {
        containerRegistry.Register< IUssdRenderer, UssdRenderer>(); 
    }
```

The last bit is to make sure you have Call permissions enabled :

Right click on Android Project > Options > Android application

```
make sure CallPhone is selected
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use Xamarin.Essentials PhoneDialer, to make a call, note that since USSD contains '#' you need to URL-encode it. example:

```
string code = "*123#";
PhoneDialer.Open(HttpUtility.UrlEncode(code));
```

Answer (score 1):

After collecting from left and right  I finally found the solution to my question with CrossMessaging plugin.

The steps are as follow:

1. Create your project and give the name
2. Install from nuget `Xam.Plugins.Messaging` in your project
3. Add below line in Android project MainActivity's OnCreate method:
   `CrossMessaging.Current.Settings().Phone.AutoDial = true;`
4. Add `android.permission.CALL_PHONE` to the manifest file.
5. Make calls as follow

```cs
    try
    {
        var phonedialer = CrossMessaging.Current.PhoneDialer;

        if (phonedialer.CanMakePhoneCall)
        {
            //Ussd call's
            phonedialer.MakePhoneCall(HttpUtility.UrlEncode("#150#"));

            //For normal calls
            phonedialer.MakePhoneCall("9111111111")
        }
    }
    catch (Exception  exc)
    {
        await DisplayAlert("Error!!!!", exc.ToString(), "ok");
    }
```