# How can we launched the dialler directly from xamarin prepopulating it a with number containing #

Tags: android, ios, call, launch, ussd

I wish to write a program in xamarin cross platform that will populate (#123#) and launched  the dialler with one click in the xamarin app. I am very new in xamarin... your help is of great neeed.thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the concern. I finally got the solution here is it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51030666/make-a-ussd-call-in-xamarin-crossplatform-app/70835035#70835035

Answer (score 0):

You can Open Dialer in Xamarin using Xamarin.Essentials. here is step by step guidance.

Open the **AndroidManifest.xml** file under the Properties folder and add the following inside of the manifest node:

```
<queries>
  <intent>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.DIAL" />
    <data android:scheme="tel"/>
  </intent>
</queries>
```

using Xamarin.Essentials;

Call using,   `PhoneDialer.Open(number);`

Comment: Sorry for the late response. Please krunal when I dial #123# and click in xamarin, it only open the dialler with no action. Whereas I want to launched the ussd. It shows as if it doesn't recognize the #123#, but when I dial normal phone number it only opens the dialler and paste the number. Please can you help...thanks for your concern.

Comment: @Larmel : I got your point. can you follow this StackoverFlow Link it helps. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51030666/make-a-ussd-call-in-xamarin-crossplatform-app

Comment: I have try the link and I am unable to implement the work of LeRoy .it seems the is something missing, that of hakim83 does not work. Can you help me with that of LeRoy please if you have an idea ??

Comment: Sorry not worked with that feature. I was just trying to help you.